# Is it possible to evaluate this integral for general volume $V$?

Tags: calculus, integration, harmonic-functions, divergence-operator

If, for a volume $V$ in three dimensions, we have

$$\nabla ^2 u=0 \qquad \text{ in }V \\ u(x,y,z) = ax+by+cz \qquad \text{ on } \partial V$$

then is it possible to find the value of the integral

$$\int_V(u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2)\; dxdydz$$

in terms of the volume of $V$, without knowing what $V$ or $u$ is?

---

I tried the following

\begin{align}
& \int_V(u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2)\; dxdydz \\
= & \int_V(u_x^2+u_y^2+u_z^2 + u\nabla^2u)\; dxdydz \\
= & \int_V\big[(uu_{xx}+u_x^2)+(uu_{yy}+u_y^2)+(uu_{zz}+u_z^2) \big] \; dxdydz \\
= & \int_V\big[(uu_x)_x+(uu_y)_y+(uu_z)_z \big] \; dxdydz \\
= & \int_V\nabla \cdot (u\nabla u) \; dxdydz \\
= & \int_{\partial V} (u\nabla u) \cdot \mathbf n \; dS && \text{Divergence Theorem}
\end{align}

and then I kinda got stuck.

Is it actually possible, or would I have to solve for $u$ first?

Answer (score 1):

${\rm grad}\ u_x=0$ so that $u_x$ is constant. So $u$ is linear
function on the whole $V$.

Hence we must find $$ \ast=(a^2+b^2+c^2)\int_{x\in \partial V}\
v\cdot x\ v\cdot n\ dx
$$

where $v= \frac{(a,b,c)}{|(a,b,c)|}$

If $h(x)=v\cdot x$, then $h: \partial V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a
height function.

If $\textbf{x} : (a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow
\partial V$ is a parametrization, then $v\cdot n\ dx $ is corresponded to $
\textbf{x}_a\times \textbf{x}_b \cdot v $

(1) Here $\int_{\partial V}\ v\cdot n \ dx=0$ if $\partial V$ is
homeomorphic to a sphere.

(2) If $\partial V=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3||x|=1\}$, then $v\cdot n\
dx$ is area form of unit ball $\{ y\in \mathbb{R}^2||y|=1\}$ and $h$
is height so that $\ast$ is a volume of unit ball in $
\mathbb{R}^3$.